# Change custom entity fields

Tags: 7, entities

I'm facing very strange problem with changing my custom entity's fields. I've a custom entity with `id`, `type`, .. , `premium`, `premium_expires_at`, .. fields. It was  working without any problems with its own fields (those declared in hook_schema()) till today, but suddenly I changed its fields, dropped `premium`, and `premium_expires_at` fields, added new fields with `HOOK _update_n` function. I see database schema changed, but those deleted fields are still being shown in `base table` key under `field_sql_storage` key.. I've already ran update.php (many times), but no luck.. I thought it's a caching problem, so I've cleared all caches manually, and with drush, no luck, cleared memcached data (with telnet), any changes.Every time I'm getting the same error, like this:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.premium' in 'field list': SELECT ... base.premium AS premium... в функции EntityCacheControllerHelper::entityCacheLoad() (строка 101 в файле /PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/sites/all/modules/entitycache/entitycache.module)

I don't have any `premium` field in my db schema, but still getting this error, is there any way to solve it?

(I am using EntityAPI with Entitycache and Memcache Storage modules).

Comment: Try clearing the cache bins manually (all of them). That error would suggest entitycache is still getting stale data

Comment: @Clive hi, thanks for the response. I've already cleared them, multiple times, all tables with beginng cache*..

Comment: Have you completely removed the memcache data (i.e. used `flush_all`)?

Comment: @Clive yes, removed them with telnet 127.0.0.1 11212 (11212 this is the port wich my project uses) -> flush_all..

Comment: Probably the next thing is to uninstall entitycache completely (not just disable), see if the problem persists. It probably won't, then you should be able to re-install entitycache and be on your way. In theory at least

Comment: @Clive Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my question, I also tried this, the same problem is appearing in `entity.controller.inc -> $query = $this->buildQuery($ids, $conditions, $revision_id);' line after uninstalling Entitycache module, I'm thinking this issue belongs to EntityAPI module somehow..

Comment: @Clive I posted my own answer, may be you check it? May be you can find better solution? it seems it's not a normal solution to me..

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem somehow.. I think this is an EntityAPI's issue. So, here is my (temporary) solution:

- removed those changed fields directly from `hook_schema`, added new fields directly to it.
- removed those fields with `db_drop_field` function and added new fields with `db_add_field` function with `hook_update_n` function. By this way I managed to have the same structure in my (changed) entity and db table schema.
- flushed the caches

Error has gone, so far everything is working fine. But I'm not sure this solution will not cause any problems in future... I still can't understand why entity api doesn't see changed fields in `hook_update_n` function...